# Net Core Query String Encryption

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, asp.net-core, query-string

I am trying to do something along the lines of:

`private IDataProtector _protector;`

```
public PieController(IPieRepository pieRepository, ICategoryRepository categoryRepository, IDataProtectionProvider provider)
{
    _pieRepository = pieRepository;
    _categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
    _protector = provider.CreateProtector(GetType().FullName);
}

public IActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var pie = _pieRepository.GetPieById(id);
    pie.PieId = _protector.Protect(pie.PieId.ToString());
    if (pie == null)
        return NotFound();

    return View(pie);
}
```

I am trying to encrypt the PieId within the query string so that it does not show to the user. Since the `IDataProtector` only works with `strings` I am having issues trying to come up with a way to insert the PieId which is an `int`. Any suggestions?

I tried:
`pie.PieId = Int32.Parse(_protector.Protect(pie.PieId.ToString()));` and `pie.PieId = Convert.ToInt32(_protector.Protect(pie.PieId.ToString()));` but neither worked.

I am basing this off of [this](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/295/encryption-and-decryption-in-asp-net-core) example.

Comment: Do you need to encrypt or just obfuscate?

Comment: @maccettura I need to be able to generate an encrypted querystring and be able to decrypt said querystring to work with the data...

Comment: @Milo you can't do that: the ciphertext returned by `IDataProtector.Protect()` can't be cast to an integer. You should either use strings in your model or use a dedicated view model, exposing the Pie identifier as a string.

Comment: @Pinpoint thank you, I will try the ViewModel approach. Btw is there any bad reasons to have an object id as a `string` instead of `int`?